# How to include parameters when exporting db to csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, redmine

I'm trying to export a set of records to a csv file in my Redmine plugin. The records are stored in mysql database, which has a column `project_id` to tie each record to a particular project. I want to export only the records that match some value for `project_id`.

app/controllers/foo_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :find_project

def index
  @foos = Foo.order(:id).where("project_id = ?", @project.id) # csv request throws NoMethodError here because @project is nil.
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @foos.to_csv(:col_sep => ",") }
  end
end

private
def find_project
  if params[:project_id].present?
    @project = Project.find params[:project_id]
  end
end
```

init.rb

```
Redmine::Plugin.register :foo_plugin do
  # Some info stuff...
  # Some module/permission stuff...

  menu :project_menu, :foos, {:controller => 'foo_con', :action => 'index'}, :caption => 'Foos', :param => :project_id

end
```

From what I can tell, the issue is with how the csv request is handled in rails. When the index page is first loaded, `project_id` is auto included in the `params` array. But when it reloads `index` to handle the csv request, `project_id` doesn't get added into the `params` array. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any links creating a `.csv` request. Include `:format => 'csv'` in your menu link.

Also, you may need some extra information in your `send_data` for the export. For example:

```
 format.csv  { send_data(@foos.to_csv, :type => 'text/csv; header=present', :filename => 'issues.csv') }
```

On a side note, Redmine has built in CSV exporting for a valid `@query`. You can take advantage by doing something like this:

```
cond = "project_id IS NULL"
cond << " OR project_id = #{@project.id}" if @project
@query = IssueQuery.where(cond)

respond_to do |format|
    # ...
    format.csv  { send_data(query_to_csv(@issues, @query, params), :type => 'text/csv; header=present', :filename => 'issues.csv') }
    # ...
```

The `query_to_csv` function is within the `queries_helper.rb`:

```
def query_to_csv(items, query, options={})
    encoding = l(:general_csv_encoding)
    columns = (options[:columns] == 'all' ? query.available_inline_columns : query.inline_columns)
    query.available_block_columns.each do |column|
      if options[column.name].present?
        columns << column
      end
    end

    export = FCSV.generate(:col_sep => l(:general_csv_separator)) do |csv|
      # csv header fields
      csv << columns.collect {|c| Redmine::CodesetUtil.from_utf8(c.caption.to_s, encoding) }
      # csv lines
      items.each do |item|
        csv << columns.collect {|c| Redmine::CodesetUtil.from_utf8(csv_content(c, item), encoding) }
      end
    end
    export
  end
```